# Differential calculus of functions of self-adjoint operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, functional-calculus

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$. Fix a self-adjoint operator $A:D(A)\rightarrow H$ and a Borel function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. The operator $f(A)$ is defined by the spectral theorem.

I wonder whether under certain assumptions on $f$ and $A$, something of the following form $$f(A+B）=f(A)+L(B)+o(\|B\|)$$ can be concluded for $B$ bounded and symmetric. Here $L$ denotes a bounded ($\mathbb{R}$-)linear map from the space of (symmetric) bounded operators to the space of bounded operators on $H$. (In general, self-adjointness is lost under scaling by a complex number, so I can only hope to deal with real scalars.)

In my specific problem, $H$ is finite-dimensional, $f$ is smooth but not necessarily analytic. I am also interested in what happens for infinite-dimensional $H$ (and thus possibly stronger assumptions on $f$.)

Comment: If $H$ is finite-dimensional, surely this is exactly Taylor's theorem?

Comment: @NateEldredge I think it is not exactly Taylor's theorem, because the connection between the function on $\mathbb R$ and the function of matrices is not so direct.

Comment: So perhaps the question is, under what conditions on $f,A$ is the induced function of matrices differentiable at $A$.  Francois's answer says that it's sufficient for $f$ to be analytic on a neighborhood of $\sigma(A)$ but that's surely not necessary.

Comment: I guess that $f'$ continuous and bounded on an open nbd $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ of $\sigma(A)$  should make $h\mapsto f(A+h)-f(A)$ Fréchet differentiable in a nbd of $0$ of $B(H)$ with values in $B(H)$ (wrto the operator norm), or in other words, $L\mapsto f(L)$ differentiable as a map between "affine $B(H)$ manifolds"

Answer (score 4):

J. T. Schwartz ([1955](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=82644)) has something like this, for analytic $f$. He says a function $f(A)$, defined for $A$ in some open set of bounded operators on a Banach space, *has Frechet derivative* $L$ (a linear map from bounded operators to bounded operators, which he denotes $df(A)/dA$), if
$$
\left.\frac d{d\epsilon}f(A+\epsilon B)\right|_{\epsilon=0} = L(B),\qquad\text{i.e.}\qquad
f(A+\epsilon B)=f(A)+\epsilon L(B)+o(\epsilon).
$$
He proves (p. 375):

> **Theorem 2**: Let $f(z)$ be a function analytic in a neighborhood $D$ of the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of a bounded operator $A$. Then $f(S)$ is defined for every operator $S$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $A$, and the operator-valued function $f(S)$ of $S$ has a Frechet derivative $df(A)/dA$.

Comment: In this case more is true and more in general: If $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is analytic, and $\mathbb{B}$ is a Banach algebra, then the functional calculus $a\mapsto f(a)$ defines an analytic map  on the open subset of  $\mathbb{B}$,  $\tilde\Omega:=\{a\in \mathbb{B} : \sigma(a)\subset\Omega\};$ its higher  differentials can be obtained differentiating the Cauchy integral in the definition of $f(a)$:
$$d^mf(a)[h]^m={m!\over 2\pi i}\int_\gamma f(\zeta)(\zeta -a)^{-1} h\ (\zeta -a)^{-1}h \dots h\ (\zeta -a)^{-1}d\zeta .$$

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $\|A\|=\|B\|=1$, just to fix some normalisation. Our aim is to show that the limit $\frac{f(A+\varepsilon B) - f(A)}{\varepsilon}$ exists and is linear in $B$. By using a mollifier, we may assume that $f$ is compactly supported since we only care about values of around the spectrum, which is contained in the interval $[-2,2]$. It follows that the derivative is a Fourier transform of a nice function $g$, in particular integrable. We may then write
$$
f(x)-f(y) = i \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{-isx}-e^{-isy}}{s} g(s) ds.
$$
Plugging in $A+\varepsilon B$ for $x$ and $A$ for $y$ we get
$$
f(A+\varepsilon B) - f(A) = i \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{-is(A+\varepsilon B)} - e^{-isA}}{s} g(s) ds.
$$
Note now that the following formula holds (which essentially follows from the fact that it is easy to differentiate exponentials):
$$
e^{-iS} - e^{-iT} = -i\int_{0}^{1} e^{itS} (S-T) e^{i(1-t)T} dt.
$$
If you apply it for $S= s(A+\varepsilon B)$ and $T=sA$, you get
$$
f(A+\varepsilon B) - f(A) = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-its(A+\varepsilon B)} \varepsilon B e^{-i(1-t)sA}g(s)ds\right) dt,
$$
so
$$
\frac{f(A+\varepsilon B) - f(A)}{\varepsilon} = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-its(A+\varepsilon B)} B e^{-i(1-t)sA}g(s)ds\right) dt.
$$
We can now use dominated convergence theorem to show that the limit exists and is equal to
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{f(A+\varepsilon B) - f(A)}{\varepsilon} = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-itsA} B e^{-i(1-t)sA}g(s)ds\right) dt.
$$
To conclude, one exploits Fourier transform to write our function $f$ as an integral of analytic functions for which the result is easy.

EDIT: Once we know the formula for the derivative, we can actually check that this is a Fréchet derivative. The formula for the derivative at point $A$ in the direction $B$ is
$$
D_{A}(B):=\int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-itsA} B e^{-i(1-t)sA}g(s)ds\right) dt.
$$
So we get 
$$
f(A+B) - f(A) - D_{A}(B) = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} (e^{-its(A+B)}-e^{-itsA}) B e^{-i(1-t)sA}g(s)ds\right) dt.
$$
From the formula $e^{-iS} - e^{-iT} = -i\int_{0}^{1} e^{itS} (S-T) e^{i(1-t)T} dt$ we conclude that $\|e^{-iS} - e^{-iT}\| \leqslant \|S-T\|$, so
$$
\|f(A+B) - f(A) - D_{A}(B)\| \leqslant \int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} ts \|B\|^2 |g|(s) ds \right) dt,
$$
from which we get
$$
\frac{\|f(A+B) - f(A) - D_{A}(B)\|}{\|B\|} \leqslant \|B\| \int_{0}^{1} t \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} s |g|(s) ds\right) dt.
$$
So we only need to assume additionally that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} s |g|(s) ds < \infty$, which is satisfied under mild smoothness assumption on $f$.

Comment: This proves that $A\mapsto f(A)$ is G-differentiable; can  you also bound uniformly the remainder wrto $B$, to show $A\mapsto f(A)$ is even Fréchet differentiable?

Comment: I think so, once I know the formula for the derivative I can use the formula for the difference of exponentials once more to check that the remainder can be controlled. I will add the details at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $A$ has discrete spectrum consisting of   eigenvalues with finite multiplicities

$$ 0<\lambda_1 < \lambda_2<\cdots   $$

with $\lambda_n\to\infty$ as $n\to \infty$. Denote by $(\psi_n)$   an orthonormal  basis consisting of e-vectors of $A$.  In this basis $A$ is an (infinite) diagonal matrix $\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}$

$$ A=\diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dotsc, ...).$$

Then $\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}$

$$f(A+\ve I)=\diag( f(\lambda_1+\ve), f(\lambda_2+\ve),\dotsc),..). $$

Assume that $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$  $f:\bR\to\bR$ is $C^2$. Then

$$ f(\lambda_n+\ve I)=f(\lambda_n)+\ve f'(\lambda_n)\ve+ \frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_n)\ve^2,\;\;\xi_n\in (\lambda_n,\lambda_n+\ve). $$

Suppose more concretely that $f(x)=x^3$. The above shows that $f(A+\ve I)-f(A)$ is not bounded.

This may not be as surprising since $A^3$ is not a bounded operators.  Here is a more interesting examples.

Suppose for simplicity that  $\lambda_n=n$ and $f$ is a  $C^2$ function such that for $|x-n|<0.1$ we have $f(x)=n^2\cos (x-n)-n^2+1$. Note that

$$f(\lambda_n)=1,\;\;\forall n $$

so $f(A)=I$.  Consider the bounded operator

$$ B=\diag( 1^{-1/2}, 2^{-1/2},\dotsc, n^{-1/2},\dotsc, ). $$

Then

$$f(A+\ve B)-f(A)=\diag(\dotsc, f(n+\ve n^{-1/2})-f(n),\dotsc), $$

and   we observe  that,  if $\ve<0.1$, then

$$   f(n+\ve n^{-1/2})-f(n) =n^2\cos\ve n^{-1/2}.  $$

We deduce that $f(A+\ve B)-f(A)$ is not bounded.

**Remark**  (a) Here is a possible reformulations.   There are  several natural topologies on the space of  closed selfadjoint operators; see [this paper](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/bofu.pdf).  One of them, called  *gap topology* in the above paper  is defined by a certain metric $\gamma$ (distance between the graphs)   and has the property

$$\gamma(A_n,A)\to 0 \,\Longleftrightarrow\; \Vert f(A_n)- f(A)\Vert\to 0,\;\;\forall f\in C_0(\bR), $$

where $C_0(\bR)$ denotes the space of   continuous functions $f:\bR\to\bR$ such that

$$\lim_{t\to\pm\infty} f(t)=0. $$

It may be the  case that if $f\in C^2(\bR)$ is such that $f,f', f''\in C_0(\bR)$ then a conclusion of the type you've formulated could be true.

(b) Let me  mention a closely related question. The set of closed selfadjoint *Fredholm* operators on $H$, equipped with the above gap topology  can be  organized as a   Banach manifold.  More precisely it is an open dense subset $\newcommand{\eO}{\mathscr{O}}$ $\eO$ of  $\DeclareMathOperator{\Lag}{Lag}$ $\Lag(H\oplus L)$  Grassmannian of Lagrangian subspaces of $H\oplus H$; see [this paper](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/scalc.pdf) or  [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.2563v3.pdf)  for more details.  The above remark  shows that any $f\in C_0(\bR)$ defines a continuous function $\hat{f}:\eO\to\bR$, $A\mapsto f(A)$ and I am $52$% sure  that it extends to $\Lag(H\oplus H)$. Is it true that if $f\in C_0(\bR)$  is such that $f'\in C_0(\bR)$ that $\hat{f}$ is a $C^1$-function on $\eO$?

Comment: That's a good point. If one wants such a thing for unbounded operators then one has to demand appropriate decay of the function $f$.

Comment: In your second example the difference is a bounded operator, simply because $f$ is a bounded function. The mistake is that the second derivative $f''(x) = -n^2 \cos(n(x-n))$ can be small for some  $\xi_n \in (n, n + \varepsilon n^{-\frac{1}{2}})$.

Comment: @Mateusz Wasiewski I realized this on my way to school. I'll update my example.

Comment: If $f(x) = n^2\cos(x-n)$ then $f(A)$ is no longer equal to identity, because $f(\lambda_n) = n^2$. It seems to me that the convergence in gap metric is often called convergence in the norm resolvent sense (at least this is the name that Reed and Simon attach to it).

Comment: Oops!, you're right. How about $n\cos(x-n)-n+1$?

Comment: @MateuszWasilewski  You are correct. The gap topology is the topology of the convergence in resolvent.  The term *gap  topology* is inspired from Kato's book on the perturbation of linear operators  and it's the more appropriate  concept if one deals with subspaces of $H\oplus H$ that are not graph of operators.

Comment: If you correct $n^2 \cos(x-n) - n+1$ to $n^2\cos(x-n) - n^2+1$ then it works. This has to do with operator Lipschitz functions -- actually a lot is known about functions that satisfy inequalities of the form $\|f(A) - f(B)\| \leqslant C \|A-B\|$. If you have a function that is not operator Lipschitz then you can always construct an appropriate example, using a block-diagonal construction.

Comment: In example **2** one can also  take $f(x):=\cos(2\pi x^2)$ , with the same sequence $\lambda:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, given by $\lambda_n:=n$. In a sense it is not surprising that $f(A)$ is not differentiable wrto bounded perturbations of $A$, because already on the $\ell_\infty$ affine space $\lambda+\ell_\infty$ the composition map $u\mapsto f(u)$ is not differentiable, due to the fact that $f'$ is not bounded.